# Typescript error Property 'lineNumber' does not exist on type 'Error'

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I am trying to get the line number of an Error i pass to the logging method which works fine in Javascript but gives an error in Typescript

```
private logger(msg : string, error : Error) {
    var l=error.lineNumber;
    console.info('info: ' + msg + " lineno: "+l);
}
```

when I replace the assignment with one that casts the object to any first, it works, I assume in this case the properties are not checked at all.

```
var e=<any>error;
var l=e.lineNumber;
```

Does this work using a different class or casting the object to something else?

Comment: Well a normal `Error` *doesn't* have a `.lineNumber`. [It is a non-standard Firefox-only extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber), and as such not accepted by TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `error` to `Error & { lineNumber: number }` so you maintain type safety. [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) completely turns off type checks.

```
function logger(msg: string, error: Error) {
  let l = (error as Error & { lineNumber: number }).lineNumber;
  error.notExists;
  //    ~~~~~~~~~ Property 'notExists' does not exist on type 'Error'.
  console.info("info: " + msg + " lineno: " + l);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgczQUwE4AoC2AzmgFyKFTYxhoA0iO2c2ZAotk9gJSIDeAUIhSYoKRAF5EuRs0QBDQonadEAMj4pqmAHIh8AIxxkwew9kQBfLgDpkW3QZwBuQQw7NrYOFFYAPGBSELkIA9CFCQgB+0TExiAAKTAAOOFAAnogA5F4+-oGZiAAmcJiKOQx5ogiI6SlZysyZ1q4QCIRwyJjW1MBwuABEPXBk-YgA1IhEaOOIo3ZgmF4jM8hcLhb8QA)